# Spotfire Information Link caching does not work

Tags: spotfire, spotfire-webplayer, spotfire-analyst

I tried caching an information link by using the Spotfire Analyst caching option in Information Designer,
have set the timer to 7200s and don't have an validation query.

Unfortunately when I try to open/import the data it still tries to load them from scratch.
I know that for the first time, you need to wait for the data to load but even after after the first when I try to load them again it still brings them from from scratch so I have to wait 4-5 minutes for 4GB of data to load.

I checked the Spotfire server logs and it seems that it uses the cache but I don't know why it takes so much time.
Is there anything I can do to figure out what's happening?

Comment: What does the server logs say more specifically? Have you just seen that the cache is enabled in general or do you see that it actually uses the cache when you execute the information link the second time (you should get a log entry like `Information Link cache hit`)?

The cache is server-side so if the connection between your computer and the Spotfire Server is slow then that might also be the limiting factor.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this is because the settings in the server configuration tool, for the Attachment Manager, are left at default, which limits the overall time period and the total amount of storage the caching can consume on the server.  I find these values too low and increase them substantially.